# In yahoo pipes, how can I combine 2 fields?

Tags: yahoo-pipes

I am trying to modify a title of a rss field to include text from another field.  How can I put these two fields together to make a new field?
Thanks,
CP

Answer (score 1):

You can combine two fields using the **Regex** operator, by using `${...}` notation in the replacement pattern to refer to other fields.

For example, if you want to replace the `title` field with the combination of the `pubDate` and `link` fields, you could set the parameters like this:

- **In:** `item.title`
- **replace:** `.*`
- **with:** `${pubDate} - ${link}`

In the **replace** parameter I used `.*` to match the entire content of `item.title`, and in **with** `${pubDate}` will be replaced with the content of `item.pubDate`, and `${link}` with the content of `item.link`.

Some more examples and screenshots:

[image: replacing a field with the combination of other fields]

If you want to create a new field with the combination of others:

[image: creating a new field with the combination of other fields]

If you want to prepend something to an existing field:

[image: prepending another field to an existing field]