# Adding item.title to item.link in Yahoo Pipes

Tags: regex, rss, yahoo-pipes

I need to build a **Yahoo! Pipe** that copies the **item.title** element and adds it to the end of the **item.link** element.

Example input:

```
<item>
  <title>helloworld</title>
  <link>http://www.example.com/abc</link>
</item>
<item>
  <title>whatsup</title>
  <link>http://www.example.com/def</link>
</item>
```

Example output:

```
<item>
  <title>helloworld</title>
  <link>http://www.example.com/abc?helloworld</link>
</item>
<item>
  <title>whatsup</title>
  <link>http://www.example.com/def?whatsup</link>
</item>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that using the **Regex** operator, by using `${...}` notation in the replacement pattern to refer to other fields, in this case `${title}`:

- **In:** `item.link`
- **replace:** `$`
- **with:** `- ${title}`

In the **replace** parameter I used `$` to match the end of `item.link`, and in **with** `${title}` will be replaced with the content of `item.title`, thus appending to the end of `item.link`.

FYI this other question covers a more general case of combining two fields:

[In yahoo pipes, how can I combine 2 fields?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23398105/in-yahoo-pipes-how-can-i-combine-2-fields)

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thank you Janos :)